# Can't dismiss ModalViewController

Tags: swift, ios8, xcode6, segue, modalviewcontroller

I've got a problem by dismissing a ViewController programmatically. 
I connected both Controllers and if I press the Button, the Controller will be presented.
Here is my prepareForSegue method:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    let VC = VC()
    let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffectStyle.Dark)
    let blurredView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
    blurredView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height + 64)

    VC.view.frame = self.view.bounds
    VC.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    VC.view.addSubview(blurredView)
    VC.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.OverCurrentContext

    var masterViewOfVC = (segue.destinationViewController as! SubjectSelectionViewController).masterView

    blurredView.addSubview(masterViewOfVC)

    masterViewOfVC.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)

    let views = ["masterView": masterViewOfVC]

    let horizontalConstraintsForMasterView = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|[masterView]|", options: .AlignAllCenterY, metrics: nil, views: views)
    blurredView.addConstraints(horizontalConstraintsForMasterView)
    let verticalConstraintsForMasterView = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|[masterView]|", options: .AlignAllCenterX, metrics: nil, views: views)
    blurredView.addConstraints(verticalConstraintsForMasterView)

    (segue.destinationViewController as! VC).viewDidLoad()

    self.presentViewController(VC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

So and if I try to dismiss it it doesn't do anything. I already checked if the buttons works and it does.

Here is my code from the other controller:

//viewDidLoad

```
cancelButton.setTitle("Abbrechen", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    cancelButton.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    cancelButton.addTarget(self, action: Selector("buttonAction:"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    cancelButton.enabled = true
```

//my function

```
func buttonAction(sender:UIButton!) {
    VC().dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

UPDATE

---

I delete the segue in my Storyboard and I created a modal segue in the IBAction of my Button. I also initialise my "dismiss button" in this action.

Here is my code from the parentViewController:

```
@IBAction func SubjectSelctionButtonPressed(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    let subjectSelectionViewController = SubjectSelectionViewController()
    let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffectStyle.Dark)
    let blurredView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
    blurredView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height + 64)

    subjectSelectionViewController.view.frame = self.view.bounds
    subjectSelectionViewController.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    subjectSelectionViewController.view.addSubview(blurredView)
    subjectSelectionViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.OverCurrentContext

    var masterViewOfSubjectSelection = SubjectSelectionViewController().masterView
    var buttonOfSubjectSelection = SubjectSelectionViewController().cancelButton

    buttonOfSubjectSelection.setTitle("Abbrechen", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    buttonOfSubjectSelection.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    buttonOfSubjectSelection.addTarget(self, action: Selector("buttonAction:"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

    blurredView.addSubview(masterViewOfSubjectSelection)
    masterViewOfSubjectSelection.addSubview(buttonOfSubjectSelection)

    masterViewOfSubjectSelection.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)

    let views = ["masterView": masterViewOfSubjectSelection]

    let horizontalConstraintsForMasterView = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|[masterView]|", options: .AlignAllCenterY, metrics: nil, views: views)
    blurredView.addConstraints(horizontalConstraintsForMasterView)
    let verticalConstraintsForMasterView = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|[masterView]|", options: .AlignAllCenterX, metrics: nil, views: views)
    blurredView.addConstraints(verticalConstraintsForMasterView)

    self.presentViewController(subjectSelectionViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

and the action from the button looks like this:

```
func buttonAction(sender:UIButton!) {
    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

ok now, when the controller is presenting there is nothing except my elements which I created in the action. My viewDidLoad() method of my presenting Controller is called but the constraints and the formattings doesn't get called...

Here is my viewDidLoad() of my modalViewController:

```
        titleLabel.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
    cancelButton.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
    separatorLine.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
    subjectsTableView.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)

    subjectsTableView.delegate = self

    titleLabel.text = "Unterrichtsfächer"
    titleLabel.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    titleLabel.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Medium", size: 17)

    separatorLine.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

    subjectsTableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()

    masterView.addSubview(titleLabel)
    masterView.addSubview(cancelButton)
    masterView.addSubview(separatorLine)
    masterView.addSubview(subjectsTableView)

    let views = ["line": separatorLine, "title": titleLabel, "button": cancelButton, "table": subjectsTableView]

    let verticalConstraintsForElements = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-64-[line(2)][table]|", options: .AlignAllCenterX, metrics: nil, views: views)
    masterView.addConstraints(verticalConstraintsForElements)
    let horizontalConstraintsForSeparatorLine = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|[line]|", options: .AlignAllCenterY, metrics: nil, views: views)
    masterView.addConstraints(horizontalConstraintsForSeparatorLine)
    let horizontalConstraintsForTableView = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|[table]|", options: .AlignAllCenterY, metrics: nil, views: views)
    masterView.addConstraints(horizontalConstraintsForTableView)

    let verticalConstraintsForTitleLabel = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:[title(21)]-11-[line]", options: .AlignAllCenterX, metrics: nil, views: views)
    masterView.addConstraints(verticalConstraintsForTitleLabel)

    let horizontalAlignmentForTitleLabel = NSLayoutConstraint(item: titleLabel, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: masterView, attribute: .CenterX, multiplier: 1, constant: -18)
    masterView.addConstraint(horizontalAlignmentForTitleLabel)
    let widthForTitleLabel = NSLayoutConstraint(item: titleLabel, attribute: .Width, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 137)
    masterView.addConstraint(widthForTitleLabel)

    let verticalConstraintsForCancelButton = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:[button(30)]-6-[line]", options: .AlignAllCenterX, metrics: nil, views: views)
    masterView.addConstraints(verticalConstraintsForCancelButton)
    let horizontalConstraintsForCancelButton = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:[button(90)]-7-|", options: .AlignAllCenterY, metrics: nil, views: views)
    masterView.addConstraints(horizontalConstraintsForCancelButton)
```

Can anybody help me?
Thank you very much!!!

Comment: your `buttonAction` dismisses a new instance of `VC` and not the one that already exists.

Comment: ok... How can i fix that?

Comment: I see several problems.  The segue instantiates the destination view controller for you.  Why are you doing `let VC = VC()`?  Also, you're not supposed to call `viewDidLoad()`, that is called by the system.  Third, you are calling `presentViewController` inside of `prepareForSegue`.  If you're using segues, you don't need `presentViewController`.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't really checked all your code but to fix it quickly, you can make the instance of `VC` a class property.

So it'll look something like this:

```
class MainViewController: UIViewController {
    var VC = UIViewController() // I would use an optional here but I've been down voted for suggesting people to use optionals.

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        VC = VC()

        // Your code
    }

    func buttonAction(sender:UIButton!) {
        VC.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Here I'm assuming you're using some kind of master - detail view so `buttonAction` is still accessible when you segue to `VC`.

If `buttonAction` is a method in `VC` itself, then just call `dissmissViewControllerAnimated()` on self with:

```
func buttonAction(sender:UIButton!) {
    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

Either way, you'll have to call `dissmissViewControllerAnimated()` on the instance of `VC`. With `VC()` you'll just create a **new** instance which has "nothing" to do with the one that already exists.

**Update**:
If you've created `SubjectSelectionViewController()` in your storyboard, then you probably would want to instantiate it with:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle())
let subjectSelectionViewController  = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("YourIdentifier") as! SubjectSelectionViewController
```

Comment: I also got a warning. Maybe this is something important?                  Warning: Attempt to present <VC: 0x7fe2db074f40>  on <ParentVC: 0x7fe2db034900> which is already presenting

Comment: Well, like vacawama said, there are many things in your code which are questionable. My answer just provides you a simple solution to your problem. Well, that has something to do with what vacawama said. You're preparing to segue already and also using `presentViewController` to present a view controller.

Comment: You probably want to put the code to present this `VC` in your `IBAction` of your button instead of using a segue.

Comment: Ok now the button works but my viewDidLoad method is not loading from my destinationViewController. I will update my questions!

Comment: Ok i tried it but the constraints didn't load after all

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are not pushing the other view to dismiss it, you are just adding the new view controller on top of the other view 
You need to substitute this line

```
blurredView.addSubview(masterViewOfVC)
```

For

```
presentViewController(masterViewOfVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Now when you call dismiss view controller all should just work